# how to hide objects in nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, for-loop

example.json file and related python file in the below. Can we modify it please?

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "leagues": [
                {
                    "matches": [
                        {
                            "league": "Premier League",
                            "teams": "Leeds - Chelsea",
                            "score": [
                                "3:0"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "league": "Premier League",
                            "teams": "Man Utd - Liverpool",
                            "score": [
                                "2:1"
                            ]
                        }

                    ]
                },
                {
                    "matches": [
                        {
                            "league": "La Liga",
                            "teams": "Atletico Madrid - Villareal",
                            "score": [
                                "0:2"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

this is py file I run

```
import json

with open("example2.json") as f:
    jsondata = json.load(f)

for a in jsondata["results"][0]["leagues"]:
    for b in a["matches"]:
      print(b["league"],b["teams"],b["score"][0])
```

this is output:

```
Premier League Leeds - Chelsea 3:0
Premier League Man Utd - Liverpool 2:1
La Liga Atletico Madrid - Villareal 0:2
```

I want to hide "teams" object has "Leeds" word and "league" object has "La Liga" name. how can I modify py file to get this output

```
Premier League Man Utd - Liverpool 2:1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a if condition to check like this:

```
for a in jsondata["results"][0]["leagues"]:
    for b in a["matches"]:
        if "leeds" not in b["teams"] and "La Liga" not in b["league"]:
            print(b["league"],b["teams"],b["score"][0])
```

Comment: thanks a lot @dev_998 , and do you know how can we create excel file for output of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Check those conditions before you `print` and skip that iteration of the loop if either is met:

```
      if "Leeds" in b["teams"] or "La Liga" in b["league"]:
          continue
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: is it possible to create file excel file for loop output?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely possible.

Comment: tell pls Sam. i tried with pandas but it didnot work.